# JavaScript `document.execCommand('copy')` appears successful (returns `true`), but does not write anything to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, ecmascript-6, gruntjs

I am trying to copy a text value from a hidden element to the user clipboard when the user clicks a button.

I'm using ES6, processed with Webpack and Grunt.

These are the articles I've used for reference:

[MDN: Interact with the clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

[Google: Cut and Copy Commands](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands)

I am using `document.execCommand('copy')`. I do not know about any browser compatibility issues with this method, yet.

Here is the relevant markup:

```
<div class="icon-link">
  <a href="">
    <svg id="copy_button" ... /></svg>
  </a>

  <p id="copy_confirm">Copy Link</p>
</div>

...

<p id="copy_text" style="display:none;">[text content to copy]</p>
```

And here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
const copyBtn = document.getElementById('copy_button');
const copyText = document.getElementById('copy_text');

const copyLink = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(copyText);
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);

  try {
    const successful = document.execCommand('copy');

    const msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    global.console.log(`Copy command was ${msg}`);
  } catch (err) {
    global.console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
};

doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  copyBtn.addEventListener('click', copyLink);
});
```

When I click the button, I see the "successful" message in the console. I can verify by running this code manually in the console that selecting the element and executing `document.execCommand('copy')` returns `true`.

But the contents of my clipboard are not changing.

I've verified that the page is rendering with the correct text value in the hidden element.

I've tried changing the structure of the markup to different element types, and the styling to show the element instead of hiding it; these had no effect.

I've tried using both the `Element.select()` approach from the MDN article above, and the `Range`-based approach from the Google article (shown here); both exhibit the same behavior.

I've seen some other questions about using `document.execCommand()`, but all of them seem to deal with problems related to the function returning `false`. I haven't found any that address the behavior I'm seeing.

I've tested in recent Chrome and Firefox.

Can you help me understand why the contents of my clipboard are not changing?

Comment: can't be hidden to select it.

Comment: @epascarello I've tried with the field both hidden and not hidden; I can't tell that it makes a difference. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @epascarello The fates have shifted their temperament today, and you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have tried something a little different today than my previous attempts to copy from a visible field; the issue is now resolved.

Here's the markup I'm using:

```
<div class="icon-link copy-link">
  <a href="">
    <svg id="copy_button" ... /></svg>
  </a>

  <p id="copy_confirm">Copy Link</p>
</div>

<input id="copy_text" type="text" value="[text content to copy]"/>
```

And it appears that in the JavaScript, either the `Element.select()` or the `range.selectNode()` approach will work just fine. I've left it unchanged from above.

For anyone curious, I am now hiding the `<input>` element with `transform: translateX();` and a very large negative value.